# How do I correctly use .loc in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie and trying to figure out how to correctly use the .loc function in pandas for slicing a dataframe. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The code is:

```
df1['Category'] = df[key_column].apply(lambda x: process_df1(x, 'category'))
```

where df1 is a dataframe,
key_column is a specific column identified to be operated upon
process_df1 is a function defined to run on df1.

The problem is I am trying to avoid the error:
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using

```
.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"
```

I don't want to ignore / suppress the warnings or set
`pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None.

Is there an alternative besides these 2?

I have tried using

```
df.loc[df1['Category'] = df[key_column].apply(lambda x: process_df1(x, 'category'))]
```

but it still produces the same error. Am I using the .loc incorrectly?

Apologies if it is a confusing question.

df1 = df[:break_index]
df2 = df[break_index:]

Thank you.

Comment: Hi you could try  list comprehension like this df1['Category'] = [process_df1(x,'category') for x in range(len(df1)]

Comment: what does the function `process_df1` return

Comment: share your sample data, share expected results and there may be a better way to address the problem.

Comment: Hey Tom, thank you for your reply. I corrected the syntax and now the function doesn't run at all. Sorry.

Comment: @Jeril process_df1 is a function on its own.

Comment: can you do df.head(10) and post that so we know what kind of data you are dealing with and how we need to use process_df1

Comment: what is `x1` in `process_df1` ? I cant find any reference of it

Comment: x1 is a list like ['a','b','c'] etc.

Comment: @Jeril could you verify if .loc method is being used correctly? I have many results on google that suggest using .loc will get rid of this warning.

Comment: The problem is not `apply`, on its own. Rather that `df1` is a part of a bigger dataframe and you are trying to modify just it. Your code doesn't show where and how you define `df1`. But you can try: `df.loc[df1.index, 'Category'] = df[key_column].apply(lambda x: process_df1(x, 'category'))]` where `df` is the big dataframe from which you slice `df1`.

Comment: df is broken down into df1 and df2 based on an index. so df1 = df[:break_index] and df2=[break_index:]

Answer (score 0):

The [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method performs the function in place to the series you are running it on (`key_column` in this case)

If you are trying to create a new column based upon a function using another column as input you can use list comprehension

```
df1['Category'] = [process_df1(x, 'category') for x in df1[key_column]]
```

**NOTE** I'm assuming `process_df1` operates on a single value from the `key_column` column and returns a new value based upon your writing.  If that's not the case please update your question

Comment: I have updated the question per your request. Could you please take a look now?

Comment: Also, with your code Sir, I still get the warning - "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Answer (score 0):

Unless you give more details on the source data and your expected results, we won't be able to provide you clear answer. For now, here's something I just created to help you understand how we can pass two values and get things going.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['fruit','animal','plant','fruit','animal','plant'],
                   'Good' :[27, 82, 32, 91, 99, 67],
                   'Faulty' :[10, 5, 12, 8, 2, 12],
                   'Region' :['north','north','south','south','north','south']})

def shipment(categ,y):
    d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd':3}

    if (categ,y) == ('fruit','a'):
        return 10
    elif (categ,y) == ('fruit','b'):
        return 20
    elif (categ,y) == ('animal','a'):
        return 30
    elif (categ,y) == ('animal','c'):
        return 40
    elif (categ,y) == ('plant','a'):
        return 50
    elif (categ,y) == ('plant','d'):
        return 60
    else:
        return 99

df['result'] = df['Category'].apply(lambda x: shipment(x,'a'))
print (df)
```